# Gitlab multi-runner is not able to get git repository after update 8.0

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have updated Gitlab to 8.0 version. A also integrated CI into Gitlab. But now when CI runner tries to fetch git repository it get empty repository. Error occured for both deprecated runner (that I was using before) and new `gitlab-ci-multi-runner`

Error I have

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.5.5-1-g69bc934 (69bc934)
Using Shell executor...
Running on my_server...

Fetching changes...
Checking out 9f6188d0 as super_branch...
fatal: reference is not a tree: 9f6188d0e197e0a010257d3a961c95b5a4abe504

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 128
```

Error is the same for both versions.

I checked what is git remote path. When I tried to clone it to my PC I got warning that this repository is empty and it created just `.git` directory.

Answer (score 3):

**//UPDATE**

Got it fixed ^^

The failure results from nginx/apache and the new 'gitlab-git-http-server'.
Below is a link I found in the incremental updates:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/7.14-to-8.0.md#new-nginx-configuration

As stated there,

> If you skip this step 'git clone' and 'git push' over HTTP(S) will stop working.

Basically your runner is currently talking to unicorn while it should be requesting the repo from the 'gitlab-git-http-server'.

---

For example, I'm using apache 2.4 and had to alter the gitlab file in sites-available:

from:

```
RewriteEngine on
  #forward all requests to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn) 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
```

to:

```
RewriteEngine on
  #forward request ending with .git to gitlab-git-http-server
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(git)
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  #forward any other requests to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn) 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
```

Remember to correctly reload your webserver in order to make use of your changes.

---

**//OLD**

As I've got the same problem:
Cloning the repo with the 'gitlab-runner'-user (in its specific build-dir) and eventually starting over the ci results in a (possibly) successful build.

But this is not more than a workaround, yet.
As soon as you clean the build dir, or switch branches it will crash again

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but as I am not really a server guy, I wondered where the location of the file is we have to adjust? I use a gitlab installation via Bitnami. :)

Comment: I've to admit I never used bitnami.
But the files i recommend to adjust are not gitlab files, but apache/nginx configs.

This leads to a small problem:
I've no clue what webserver you are running, and how you configured it.
But to give a probable solution (for debian based servers and a standard apache installation):
Under /etc/apache2/ there is adirectory called sites-available.
Within there should be the file you're looking for.

I either strongly recommend reading something about a2ensite or get out of the chair of "the server guy" ;)